# How I can make a button to display a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

When a user clicks the button, I want a `<div>` to show up. It does work, but only for a fraction of second it is displayed and then its hidden.

**My code is:**

```
document.getElementById("near").addEventListener("click", searchField);
function searchField() {
    document.getElementById("locationField").style.display='block';
}
```

**Code for the button:**

```
echo"<div class='row'> 
      <div class='col-md-12'> 
        <input type='submit'  class='btn' name='near' value='Near' id='near'>
        </input>
      </div>
    </div>";

echo"<div class='col-md-10'>
      <div id='locationField'  class='form-group' style='display:none'>
        <label for='autocomplete'>Type location address here</label>
        <form method='post' id='wishInput'>
          <input class='form-control' id='autocomplete' placeholder='Enter your address' onFocus='geolocate()' name='myaddress' type='text'>
          </input>
          <input  name='latitude' id='latitude'>
          <input  name='longitude' id='longitude'/>
          <input type='submit'>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>";
```

Comment: Please add the corresponding HTML.

Comment: and don't spam with irrelevant tags

Comment: `echo`? that's not javascript

Comment: That's right there in the php echo tags

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730782/show-hide-divs-with-javascript-on-a-button-press-and-have-all-divs-hidden-fir

Comment: Its impossible to tell without seeing all of your code. Either your near button is submitting a form and causing the page to refresh or you have code elsewhere that is causing the div to become hidden again.

Comment: seems to work fine https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/wePKmo make sure you give us enough code to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. Actually there were two <div>'s and i had given id to the inner one, where the outer <div> was conflicting somehow, so i gave the id to the outer one and now it's good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You should  put Javascript code after HTML then it will work fine 

<?php 
echo"<div class='row'> 
      <div class='col-md-12'> 
        <input type='submit'  class='btn' name='near' value='Near' id='near'>
        </input>
      </div>
    </div>";

echo"<div class='col-md-10'>
      <div id='locationField'  class='form-group' style='display:none'>
        <label for='autocomplete'>Type location address here</label>
        <form method='post' id='wishInput'>
          <input class='form-control' id='autocomplete' placeholder='Enter your address' onFocus='geolocate()' name='myaddress' type='text'>
          </input>
          <input  name='latitude' id='latitude'>
          <input  name='longitude' id='longitude'/>
          <input type='submit'>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>";
    ?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("near").addEventListener("click", searchField);
    function searchField() {
        document.getElementById("locationField").style.display='block';
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in different way like

```
document.getElementById("near").addEventListener("click", searchField);
function searchField() {
    document.getElementById("locationField").setAttribute("style","display : block");
}
```

And put the JavaScript code after the rendering of the whole PHP code.
Happy Coding...